# Extracting from an Integer ArrayList using another Integer ArrayList as the index

Tags: java, arraylist

Can I pull the values from a list such as "Values Wanted" using the list "Index" as an index to pull the specific integers from "Value Wanted"?

For Example, Index Value of `3` would pull `10201` from Value Wanted.

```
Index : [3, 5, 9, 12]

Value Wanted: [40000, 17956, 13689, 10201, 9216, 8281, 1296, 3969, 4356, 5776, 4660, 2025, etc.]
```

Comment: Your question's title is incorrect.  You are not "sorting" either array list.  I have fixed it.  (If you really did mean "sort", then you need to explain more clearly what you mean ...)

Comment: Your last index value is out of bounds of the wanted array, is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

you could use streams:

```
List<Integer> indices = Arrays.asList(3,5,9,12);
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(40000, 17956, 13689, 10201, 9216, 8281, 1296, 3969, 4356, 5776, 4660, 2025);
List<Integer> resultSet = indices.stream().filter(i -> i >= 0 && i < values.size())
                         .map(values::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the result would be:

```
10201
8281
5776
```

note that I've used a list in the example above only for illustration purposes and the code would perfectly work for an ArrayList aswell by using:

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultSet = indices.stream().filter(i -> i >= 0 && i < values.size())
               .map(values::get).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: I'd argue against silently dropping out of range indexes with the filter, it's better to not check and let the code blow up on bad data or check for it and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which takes indexes and values as argument. Iterate values for each index and take respective value.

```
public ArrayList extract(ArrayList indexes, ArrayList values)
{
    ArrayList extracted = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length(); i++)
    {
        extracted.add(values.get(indexes.get(i)));

    }

    return extracted;    
}
```